# Fluent Auto Mappings with abstract base also part of model

Tags: nhibernate, abstract, fluent, automapping, radix

Ok, firstly I hope this makes sense.

I'm trying to use fluent auto mappings for my app based around the following idea.

```
public abstract class Container
{
  public virtual int Id {get; set};
  public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class FirstSubClass : Container
{
   //properties and behaviour here
}

public class SecondSubClass : Container
{
  //properties of SecondSubclass Here
}

public class ProcessStep
{
   public virtual Container Source {get; set}
   public virtual Container Destination {get; set;}
}
```

However, when I try to generate the schema or test my mappings (with SQLite or otherwise) it's failing noting :

NHibernate.MappingException : An association from the table ProcessStep refers to an unmapped class: ......Entities.Container

If I change the Container class and make it none abstract it works.

Can I expose a property on an entity against a base type, with the base remaining abstract?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

By default Fluent Nhibernate ignores abstract base classes when generating mappings. 
To include it you need to use [IncludeBase](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Abstract_base-classes) method:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Container>(cfg)
       .IncludeBase<Container>();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sly. I've actually moved on since posing the question and wondered whether I can change from a abstract base to an interface. So where I've referenced Container, replace with IContainer? Is this possible as ProcessStep can't maintain any given Key Constraint. Can I then generate the schema without generating a constraint, and allowing for nulls?